# How to get the App Engine SDK to track file changes in directories added via sys.path?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am currently experiencing an issue with the Google AppEngine SDK where directories added using `sys.path` don't have their changes recognized by the SDK. Requiring the SDK be restarted in order for the modified files to have any effect.

This is particularly a problem with frameworks that make use of sys.path, such as tipfy.

Comment: Are those directories outside your app's root, or inside it?

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with file monitoring for some time and wrote
a library to do this. Hence a shameless plug:

Write a wrapper script around the dev_appserver module entry point
to restart it using a library like:
https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog

or the nosy script at
https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/blob/master/scripts/nosy.py

HTH.

Cheers,
Gora Khargosh.